# Rspec No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to add a feature that returning all movies info belonging to one director by clicking one button. It has been implemented and works well, but I got some error when writing Rspec tests. The error message is:

```
(1)MoviesController searching for movies by the same director when 'Director' info exists should post @director and @movies variables for view
 Failure/Error: get :find_movies_by_same_director, :movie_id => @movie.id, :movie_director => @movie.director

 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:movie_id=>"1", :movie_director=>["Star Wars", "THX-1138"], :controller=>"movies", :action=>"find_movies_by_same_director"}

 # ./spec/controllers/movie_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Similar errors of no routes found occured for all the following tests, so I think there might be some problems for my routes file. Here is the path I specify in routes.rb:

```
   get '/movies/:id/director', to: 'movies#find_movies_by_same_director', as: 'director'
```

And the Rspec file is:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe MoviesController do
it { should respond_to(:find_movies_by_same_director) }

describe "searching for movies by the same director" do
  context "when 'Director' info exists" do
    before do
      @movie = double(:title => "Star Wars", :id => "1", :director => "George Lucas")
      Movie.stub(:find).with("1").and_return @movie
      @lucas_films = ["Star Wars", "THX-1138"]
      @movie.stub(:director).and_return @lucas_films
    end
    it "should post @director and @movies variables for view" do
      get :find_movies_by_same_director, :movie_id => @movie.id
      assigns(:director).should == @movie.director
      assigns(:movies).should == @lucas_films
    end
  end
end
```

The controller method is:

```
def find_movies_by_same_director
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @director = @movie.director
  if (not @director.nil?) and (not @director.empty?)
    @movies = Movie.where(director: @director) if (not @director.nil?) and (not @director.empty?);
    #@movies = Movie.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM movies i WHERE i.director == '#{@director}'")
  render :director 
  else
    flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director info"
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

I just start to learn Rspec, so any comment or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen in routes, you action expects a parameter `:id`. You are passing `:movie_id` instead. So, just replace this line in your spec

```
 get :find_movies_by_same_director, :movie_id => @movie.id
```

with

```
 get :find_movies_by_same_director, :id => @movie.id
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As Jagdeep Singh suggests, your action expects an :id parameter, not an :movie_id param. But the line in your spec should pass the :id inside the params.

```
get :find_movies_by_same_director, params: { id => @movie.id }
```

I was having the same problem and this answer helped me [Controller spec unknown keyword: id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797133/controller-spec-unknown-keyword-id)