# Controller spec unknown keyword: id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have simple action show

```
def show
  @field = Field.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

and i want write spec for it

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe FieldsController, type: :controller do

    let(:field) { create(:field) }

  it 'should show field' do
    get :show, id: field
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

but I have got an error

```
Failure/Error: get :show, id: field

 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: id
```

How to fix it?

Comment: That's Rails 4 syntax. In Rails 5 and above, you need to specify the "params" keyword.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

> HTTP request methods will accept only the following keyword arguments
>   `params, headers, env, xhr, format`

According to the new API, you should use keyword arguments, `params` in this case:

```
  it 'should show field' do
    get :show, params: { id: field.id }
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
```

Comment: I had this error start appearing after upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.1 and this fixed it - thanks!

Comment: Life Saver :) But where is this new API defined? I found [this mention](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/request-specs/request-spec#specify-managing-a-widget-with-rails-integration-methods) but it would be good to see where/when/why this change happened (if you know!)

Comment: but in rails 6 im getting no  routes matches