# Ruby on Rails v5.1.3 does not pass the create test

Tags: rspec

I have the following problem

Failures:

1) `QuestionsController` POST #create with valid attributes saves the question in the database

> ```
> Failure/Error: post :create,    question: attributes_for(:question)
>
> ArgumentError:
>   unknown keyword: question
> # ./spec/controllers/questions_controller_spec.rb:68:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

2) QuestionsController POST #create with valid attributes redirect to show view

> ```
> Failure/Error: post :create,   question: attributes_for(:question)
>
> ArgumentError:
>   unknown keyword: question
> # ./spec/controllers/questions_controller_spec.rb:73:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

Finished in 0.46803 seconds (files took 7.17 seconds to load)
10 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/questions_controller_spec.rb:66 # QuestionsController POST #create with valid attributes saves the question in the database
rspec ./spec/controllers/questions_controller_spec.rb:72 # QuestionsController POST #create with valid attributes redirect to show view
```

here is the code of my controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :load_question, only: [:show, :edit]
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def show
  end  

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def load_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.create(question_params)
    redirect_to @question
  end

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body)
  end

end
```

And here's the spec question_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe QuestionsController, type: :controller do
  let(:question) {FactoryGirl.create(:question)}

  describe "GET #index" do
    let(:questions) {FactoryGirl.create_list(:question, 2)}

    before do 
      #@questions = FactoryGirl.create_list(:question, 2) #в фабрике создаем вопросы
      get :index #вызываем экшн index
    end

    it 'populates an array ot all questions'  do #должен заполнить в массив все вопросы которые вводятся 
      expect(assigns(:questions)).to match_array(questions) #проверяем в переменой questions присутствует массив из question1 и 2
    end

    it 'renders index view' do #должен отрендерит экшн view
      expect(response).to render_template :index #ожидает ,что ответ от контроллера совпадает с нашим экшном index
    end
  end

  describe "GET #show" do
    #let(:question) {FactoryGirl.create(:question)}let(:question) {FactoryGirl.create(:question)}#создаем вопрос
    before do 
      get :show, params: {id: question.id}
    end
    it 'assings the requested question to question' do #должен установливать рапрошенный вопрос
      #вызиваем экшн show с параметром id ,то есть соответствующий вопрос
      expect(assigns(:question)).to eq question
    end

    it 'renders show view' do
      expect(response).to render_template :show
    end
  end

  describe "GET #new" do
    before do 
      get :new
    end
    it 'assingns a New Question to @question' do #создает новый вопрос
      expect(assigns(:question)).to be_a_new(Question)
    end

    it 'renders new views' do
      expect(response).to render_template :new 
    end
  end

  describe "GET #edit" do
    #let(:question) {FactoryGirl.create(:question)}
    before do
      get :edit, params: {id: question.id}
    end
    it 'assings the requested question to question' do
      expect(assigns(:question)).to eq question
    end
    it 'render new view' do
      expect(response).to render_template :edit
    end 
  end

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      let(:question) {create{:question}}
      it 'saves the question in the database' do #должен сохранить вопрос в БД, если оно валидний
        old_count = Question.count
        post :create,    question: attributes_for(:question) 
        #expect { post :create, question: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:question) } .to change(Question, :count).by(1) 
        expect(Question.count).to eq (old_count + 1) # таким способом проверяется ,что добавился вопрос в БД,то есть количество возростло на 1
      end 
      it 'redirect to show view' do
        post :create,   question: attributes_for(:question) 
        expect(response).to redirect_to question_path(assigns(:question))
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

I can not find where is my error

There are also routes

```
C:\Prom\qna>rake routes
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
    questions GET    /questions(.:format)          questions#index
              POST   /questions(.:format)          questions#create
 new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)      questions#new
edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format) questions#edit
     question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#show
              PATCH  /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#update
              PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#update
              DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)      questions#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

You should state the problem right. Your problem is not the record is not created, but that test code fails itself. If you use Google, the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797133/controller-spec-unknown-keyword-id) will tell you that according to standards you need to place all your parameters in `params` hash. So you should use

`post :create, :params => { :question => attributes_for(question) }`