# Rails request specs - ArgumentError: at least 2 arguments required

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm working on my first request spec. I have the following setup.

**provider_dashboard_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"
require "spec_helper"

describe "ProviderDashboard" , :type => :request do

  let!(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }
  let!(:invalid_user) { Fabricate(:invalid_user) }

  context "when failure" do
    # 401: Unauthorized - Authentication credentials were invalid.
    # 403: Forbidden - The resource requested is not accessible - in a Rails app, this would generally be based on permissions.
    # 404: Not Found - The resource doesn’t exist on the server.

    it "returns status: 401 Unauthorized with invalid or missing credentials" do
      post "api/v1/sessions", :params => {login: invalid_user.email, passowrd: invalid_user.password}
      # expect(response.code).to be('401')
      # expect(respone.body).to include('error: ')
    end
  end
end
```

**user_fabricator.rb**

```
require 'faker'
require 'ffaker'
Fabricator(:user, from: User) do
  # user
  first_name            { FFaker::Name.first_name }
  last_name             { FFaker::Name.last_name }
  dob                   { FFaker::Time.date }
  gender                { 'Male' }
  email                 Fabricate.sequence(:email) { |i| "test_#{i}@example.com" }
  password              { '123456' }
  password_digest       { '123456' }
  password_confirmation { '123456' }
  slug                  { "#{FFaker::Name.first_name} + #{FFaker::Name.last_name}" }
end

Fabricator(:invalid_user, from: User) do
  first_name             { FFaker::Name.first_name }
  last_name              { FFaker::Name.last_name }
  dob                    { '' }
  email                  { "invalid_test@example.com" }
  password               { '' }
  password_digest        { '' }
  password_confirmation  { '' }
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'pathname'
require 'request_helper'
.
.
.
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller, type: :controller
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration, type: :feature

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'ffaker'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Fabrication::Support.find_definitions
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      with.test_framework :rspec
      with.library :rails
    end
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble understanding why #post is not accepting my url & hash as 2 arguments (located in provider_dashboard_spec.rb, first spec). I expect #post to visit the URI, using params as authentication and returning the 401.

Instead, I am receiving the ArgumentError: at least 2 arguments required. Am I not including the correct libraries in my spec or rails helper?

**Update #1**

I've changed the spec to include a header as recommended.

```
it "returns status: 401 Unauthorized with invalid or missing credentials" do
  params = {login: invalid_user.email, password: invalid_user.password}
  header = {"CONTENT_TYPE" => "text/json"}
  post "/api/v1/sessions", params, header
end
```

My error fires on the params assignment now but is the same error.

```
  1) ProvidersController when failure returns status: 401 Unauthorized with invalid or missing credentials
     Failure/Error: params = {login: invalid_user.login, password: invalid_user.password}

     ArgumentError:
       at least 2 arguments required
     # /home/barracus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/sorcery-0.9.1/lib/sorcery/model.rb:85:in `authenticate'
     # /home/barracus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/sorcery-0.9.1/lib/sorcery/controller.rb:33:in `login'
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/providers/provider_dashboard_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/barracus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /home/barracus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:100:in `cleaning'
     # /home/barracus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/barracus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.14 seconds (files took 1.65 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

**Final Update**

Turns out I had another typo `invalid_user.login` instead of `invalid_user.email` and must provide keyword args for params, headers, env & xhr format.

Thanks for the assist!

Additional source: [Top answer in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797133/controller-spec-unknown-keyword-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are probably seeing an ArgumentError because it wants arguments for `params` and `headers` in the request but it's only receiving `params`. If that doesn't resolve the issue, then please update your post with the error message in its entirety.
- You are misspelling password in your POST request as `passowrd`
- Recommendation: replace your commented-out status code examples with [HTTP status matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher) examples